# php and emailing issue

Tags: php, sendmail

recently i have discovered that i can no longer email out of php using whatever email i  choose in the "From:" header unless that domain name has a matching TXT/SPF record. otherwise, several spamming agencies will flag your IP# as naughty.

so, here is what i am thinking - have a function that checks if the email address domain name has a matching TXT record that shares the same IP number.

basically, we are looking for this TXT record:

```
> v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:199.###.184.26 ~all
```

and trying to see if that IP number matches ours.

so the results might look like this:

> From: mark@matchingIpNumber.com
>
> From: marky edwards \< mark@matchingIpNumber.com>
>
> From: apache@serverDomainName.com \r\n ReplyTo:mark@noMatchingIpNumber.com
>
> From: marky edwards \< apache@serverDomainName.com> \r\n ReplyTo: marky edwards
>   \< mark@noMatchingIpNumber.com>

my question:  has anybody else encountered this, and if so, how was it dealt with?

here is a php function i am considering to solve this problem:

```
function checkForDomainEmailMatch()     {
                /*      usage:  emailAddress
                                emailAddress name(s)

                        returns:
                                From: mark@edwardsmark.com
                                -- or --
                                From: Marky Edwards <mark@edwardsmarkf.com>
                                ReplyTo: <mark@edwardsmark.com

                */
        $input = func_get_args();

        $emailAddr      = null          ;
        $personName     = null          ;
        $ipNbr          = null          ;
        $returnResult   = 'From: '      ;

                // did we get one parameter or several ?
        if  ( is_array($input)  )       {
                $emailAddr      = array_shift($input);
                $personName     = trim(implode (' ', $input));
        } else {
                $emailAddr      = $input        ;
        }

                // get the IP number
        if (  array_key_exists('SERVER_ADDR', $_SERVER) )       {
                        // are we running locally or through apache?
                $ipNbr = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        } else {
                $ipNbr = gethostbyname(gethostname());
        }

        $domain = preg_replace('/^.*@/','',$emailAddr); 
            // strip out email prefix, just use domain name

        $ipNbrMatch = '/' . $ipNbr . '/' ;
        $dnsRecords =  dns_get_record($domain, DNS_TXT) ;
                        // EXAMPLE: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:199.231.184.26 ~all
        $dnsRecordIpNbr = null;

        foreach ( $dnsRecords as $dnsRecord )     {
                if  ( array_key_exists('txt', $dnsRecord ))     {
                        $dnsRecordIpNbr = $dnsRecord['txt']     ;
                        break;
                }
        }


        if  ( $personName )
                $returnResult   .=      $personName
                                .       '<'
                                ;

        if  ( $dnsRecordIpNbr && preg_match($ipNbrMatch, $dnsRecordIpNbr))      {
                        // our TXT IP number matches our server
                $returnResult   .= $emailAddr ;
                if  ( $personName )
                        $returnResult   .=      '>';
        } else {
                        // our TXT IP number does not match our server
                $domainName = null;
                                // looking for edwardsmarkf.info   ;-)
                $pattern[] = $ipNbrMatch;
                $pattern[] = '/ /';
                $domainName     = preg_replace($pattern, '', exec('head -1 /etc/hosts')) ;

                        // default email address
                $returnResult   .=      get_current_user()
                                .       '@'
                                .       $domainName
                                ;

                if  ( $personName )
                        $returnResult   .=      '>';

                $returnResult   .=      "\r\n"
                                .       'ReplyTo: '
                                ;

                if  ( $personName )     {
                        $returnResult   .=      $personName
                                        .       '<'
                                        ;
                }


                $returnResult   .=      $emailAddr      ;

                if  ( $personName )
                        $returnResult   .=      '>';

                $returnResult   .=      "\r\n"  ;
        }

        return $returnResult;
}
```

any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why don't you just send with a `From` under your explicit control, and set the `Reply-To` header to be the person you're sending on the behalf of.

Comment: jay - question now stated.  thank you.

Comment: ceejayoz - i have hundreds of different email addresses on file, but not all have the DNS-TXT record set to my IP number.

Answer (score 0):

this seems to be working fine - it works very with gmail.

```
 function checkForDomainEmailMatch()     {
                /*      checkForDomainEmailMatch        2014-10-27

                        usage:  emailAddress
                                emailAddress name(s)

                        returns:
                                From: mark@edwardsmark.com
                                -- or --
                                From: Marky Edwards <mark@edwardsmarkf.com>
                                Reply-To: <mark@edwardsmark.com

                */

        define('DEFAULT_EMAIL'   ,       'info@comptonpeslonline.com'    );

        $input = func_get_args();

        $emailAddr      = null          ;
        $personName     = null          ;
        $ipNbr          = null          ;
        $returnResult   = 'From: '      ;

                // did we get one parameter or several ?
        if  ( is_array($input)  )       {
                $emailAddr      = array_shift($input);
                $personName     = trim(implode (' ', $input));
        } else {
                $emailAddr      = $input        ;
        }

                        // get the IP number
        if (  array_key_exists('SERVER_ADDR', $_SERVER) )       {
                        // are we running locally or through apache?
                $ipNbr = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
        } else {
                $ipNbr = gethostbyname(gethostname());
        }

        $domain = preg_replace('/^.*@/','',$emailAddr);
                        // strip out email prefix, just use domain name

        $dnsRecords =  dns_get_record($domain, DNS_TXT) ;
                        // EXAMPLE: v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:199.231.184.26 ~all

        $dnsRecordIpNbr = null;
        foreach ( $dnsRecords as $dnsRecord )     {
                if  ( array_key_exists('txt', $dnsRecord ))     {
                        $dnsRecordIpNbr = $dnsRecord['txt']     ;
                        break;
                }
        }

        $ipNbrMatch = '/' . $ipNbr . '/' ;
        if  ( $dnsRecordIpNbr && preg_match($ipNbrMatch, $dnsRecordIpNbr))      {
                        // our TXT IP number matches our server
                if  ( $personName )
                        $returnResult   .=      $personName
                                        .       ' <'
                                        ;
                $returnResult   .= $emailAddr ;
                if  ( $personName )
                        $returnResult   .=      '>'             ;
        } else {
                if  ( $personName )     {
                        $returnResult   .=      $personName     ;
                } else {
                        $returnResult   .=      $emailAddr      ;
                }
                $returnResult           .=      ' <'             ;

                        // our TXT IP number does not match our server
                $domainName = null;
                                // looking for edwardsmarkf.info   ;-)
                $pattern[] = $ipNbrMatch;
                $pattern[] = '/ /';
                $domainName     = preg_replace($pattern, '', exec('head -1 /etc/hosts')) ;

                        // default email address
                if  ( constant('DEFAULT_EMAIL') )        {
                        $returnResult   .=      constant('DEFAULT_EMAIL')        ;
                } else {
                        $returnResult   .=      get_current_user()
                                        .       '@'
                                        .       $domainName
                                        ;
                }

                $returnResult   .=      '>';


                $returnResult   .=      "\r\n"
                                .       'Reply-To: '
                                ;

                $returnResult   .=      $emailAddr      ;

                $returnResult   .=      "\r\n"  ;
        }

        return $returnResult;
}
```

note that i just tried sending myself a paypal invoice as a test and this is what i see:

> To: mark edwards \< mark_f_edwards@oldEmailAddress.com>
>
> From: "marksPaypalAccount.com LLC via PayPal" \< member@paypal.com>
>
> Reply-To: info@marksActualDomain.com